# Производительность LINQ

Tags: linq, c#

Есть массив целых чисел. Нужно подсчитать количество элементов больше пяти.

```
int[] numbers = { 1, 3, 5, 7, 3, 2, 5, 7 };
```

Вариант с циклом:

```
int count = 0;
foreach (int n in numbers) {
    if (n > 5) {
        count++;
    }
}
```

Вариант с LINQ:

```
int count = numbers.Count(n => n > 5);
```

Что выгодней с точки зрения производительности и насколько существенна разница?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Предыдущий ответ не имеет никакого отношения к реальности. Хотелось бы примера с подтверждением наличия случая, когда *LINQ* быстрее обычного кода. Нужно понимать, что нет ничего бесплатного. Свои пять копеек стоит даже использование `foreach` вместо обычного `for`. Если необходимо писать некую библиотеку, с требованием к производительности, то надо быть очень осторожным при использовании *LINQ*. Другой вопрос, что как правило преимущества качества кода гораздо важнее некоторого падения производительности.

```
int count = 0;
//int[] numbers = { 1, 3, 5, 7, 3, 2, 5, 7 };
int N = 100000;
int RUN_COUNT = 10000;
Random r = new Random();
int[] numbers = Enumerable.Range(1, N).Select((x) => r.Next()).ToArray();


DateTime started = DateTime.Now;
for (int i = 0; i < RUN_COUNT; i++)
{
    count = 0;
    //foreach (int n in numbers)
    for (int j = 0; j < numbers.Length; j++ )
    {
        if (numbers[j] > 5)
        //if (n  > 5)
        {
            count++;
        }
    }
}

DateTime end = DateTime.Now;
TimeSpan tspan = end - started;

double iteration_time_simple = (double)tspan.TotalMilliseconds /  1000;           
//---------------------------------------------------------
started = DateTime.Now;
for (int i = 0; i < RUN_COUNT; i++)
{
     count = numbers.Count(n => n > 5);
}

end = DateTime.Now;
tspan = end - started;

double iteration_time_linq = (double)tspan.TotalMilliseconds /  1000;


Console.WriteLine("linq/simple: {0}", iteration_time_linq / iteration_time_simple);
Console.WriteLine("simple time: {0} seconds", iteration_time_simple);
Console.WriteLine("linq  time: {0} seconds", iteration_time_linq);
```

На выходе получаем:

```
linq/simple: 2.612
simple time: 7.8125 seconds
linq  time: 20.40625 seconds
```

То есть вариант с *LINQ* работает более, чем в 2.5 раза медленнее.

Мое резюме: использовать *LINQ*, но при необходимости  с помощью профилировщика переписывать совсем неадекватные места; если писать *LINQ* без ума, можно и разницу более чем в 10 раз получить и далее.

Comment: Спасибо за развернутый и обоснованный ответ.

Comment: а чем класс StopWatch не угодил вместо end = DateTime.Now; ?

Answer (score -6):

LINQ - гарантированно быстрее, чем любые вручную имплементированные циклы. Он раскладывается в более компактный ассемблер.
В конкретном примере врядли можно заметить разницу, но при работе с большим количеством текстовых данных, производительность LINQ будет заметна.
А, в общем, по LINQ: ведь качество кода (в частности, его читабельность) не менее важно, чем производительность. Подумайте, что будет легче поддерживать, 1й или 2й вариант?

Comment: Меня смущает наличие замыкания в LINQ: ведь это вызов функции, который должен нести издержки. Но, в любом случае, второй вариант поддерживать легче.

Comment: *"LINQ - гарантированно быстрее"* -- наоборот, чаще всего он медленнее.