# Проверка истинности условия для ВСЕХ объектов списка

Tags: c#, unity3d

допустим у меня есть 4 объекта, у каждого объекта висит скрипт(один и тот-же), у этого скрипта есть bool переменная. Эти объекты у меня находятся в List. И я через метод хочу проверить что у всех этих объектов значение bool переменной true и после проверки вернуть методу true если это так и false если хотя бы у одного из объектов значение false.
если честно не могу понять через что делать потому что если делать через допустим for он как только с первым объектом нашел совпадение он возвращает true методу и выходит не проверяя другие

Comment: Подправьте, пожалуйста, пунктуацию в вопросе. Расставьте запятые, заглавные буквы в начале предложений, абзацы. И ваш вопрос будет ***гораздо*** приятнее и, главное, **легче** читать

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В добавление к ответу @farkon00 добавлю более короткий вариант с использованием [LINQ](https://metanit.com/sharp/tutorial/15.1.php)

Проверим, что все элементы списка `ListName` удовлетворяют поставленному условию, используя [`Linq.All`](https://metanit.com/sharp/tutorial/15.10.php)

1. Если в массиве лежат объекты типа GameObject, и на каждом из них висит скрипт `ScriptName`, в котором нужно проверить переменную `VarName`

```
bool Foo ()
    => ListName.All(obj => obj.GetComponent<ScriptName>().VarName);
```

2. Если в массиве лежат сразу объекты типа `ScriptName`, то еще проще:

```
bool Foo ()
    => ListName.All(obj => obj.VarName);
```

---

В целом Linq конструкция `All` эквивалентна циклу, данному в первом ответе. Разница в том, что `Linq` выглядит опрятнее (он короче + посмотрев на него легче понять, что он делает, чем глядя на 8-строчную функцию), однако с большими наборами данных он может давать некий ущерб в скорости. Подробнее [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/533/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C-linq)

Answer (score 3):

Тут всё легко, это делается через foreach. В foreach запишем, что если переменная false, то возвращаем false. После foreach запишем return True;. То есть если метод ничего не вернул после фора, возвращаем True.

```
foreach (GameObject i in YourList)
{
    if (!i.GetComponent<YourScript>().YourBool)
    {
        return False;
    }
}
return True;
```

Comment: можно сократить код, использовав `Linq.All()`

Comment: Спасибо за способ, благодарен про форейч забыл. но решил через linq реализацию сделать